# DECLARE Error in MySql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
DECLARE @num INT DEFAULT = 5; 

SELECT * FROM page p LEFT JOIN categorylinks c ON p.page_id = c.cl_from 
WHERE c.cl_to = 'Art-Rock-Band' LIMIT @num

UNION ALL

SELECT * FROM page p LEFT JOIN categorylinks c ON p.page_id = c.cl_from 
WHERE c.cl_to = 'Echo-Pop-Preisträger' LIMIT @num

UNION ALL

SELECT * FROM page p LEFT JOIN categorylinks c ON p.page_id = c.cl_from 
WHERE c.cl_to = 'Englische_Band' LIMIT @num
```

It returns me the Error

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DECLARE @num INT DEFAULT = 5' at line 1

I don't know how to fix this error and the DECLARE should work.

Comment: You can try [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4f9b20/10/1). Second you need to wrap each select with `()` like `(SELECT * .... LIMIT @num) UNION ALL (SELECT * .... LIMIT @num) ...`. If not LIMIT will return only max 5 rows/not max 15 as expected

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming this is in a `begin`/`end` block, you don't need the `=` sign:

```
DECLARE @num INT DEFAULT 5;
```

Or, you can just do:

```
SET @num = 5;
```

EDIT:

Then it would appear that your block of code is not a stored program.  As the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html) explicitly states:

> The `LIMIT` clause can be used to constrain the number of rows
>   returned by the `SELECT` statement. `LIMIT` takes one or two numeric
>   arguments, which must both be nonnegative integer constants, with
>   these exceptions:
>
> - Within prepared statements, `LIMIT` parameters can be specified using ? placeholder markers.
> - Within stored programs, `LIMIT` parameters can be specified using integer-valued routine parameters or local variables.

So, what you want to do is allowed in a stored procedure, user defined function, trigger, or dynamic SQL.  It is not allowed for just any SQL query, however.

Comment: In the Case without the `=` it returns the same error. If i use SET it returns me the Error `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '@num UNION ALL SELECT * FROM page p LEFT JOIN categorylinks c ON p.page_id' at line 2` is it possible, that my mysql version does not support setting a variable?